# Populating Select box using PHP and Ajax returning empty

Tags: php, ajax

I am having an issue with an ajax function populating a list box with null options. I am fairly new to this and must be overlooking something. The DB connection is done through Sugarcrm and works, as I am using it for an auto complete function as well. I just can't seem to get the options to populate anything besides empty.

index.php

```
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'search.php',
                type: 'json',
                success:function(response){
                    var len = response.length;
                    $("#sel1").empty();
                    for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){
                        $("#sel1").append("<option value='"+name+"'></option>");

                    }
                }
            });
        });

</script>


            <select id="sel1" multiple size="6">
                <option value="0">- Select -</option>
            </select>
```

search.php

```
<?php

global $db;

$rolelistQry = "SELECT distinct name from acl_roles";


$rolelistData = $db->query($rolelistQry);

$name_array = array();

    while( $row = $rolelistData->fetch_assoc()){
        $name = $row['name'];
        $name_array[] = array("name" => $name);
    }
echo json_encode($name_array);



?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#sel1").append("<option value='"+name+"'></option>");
```

name variable doesn't exists. Try changing it to response.name

```
$("#sel1").append("<option value='"+response.name+"'>"+response.name+"</option>");
```

Comment: nvm. saw it. Anyway can you see what 'response' will return? do a quick console.log(response) and tell me what it will return

Comment: and just as skagzilla mentioned. "<option value='"+response.name+"'>"+response.name+"</option>"

Comment: Ok I see what i missed. Now it just went from '' to 'undefined'

Comment: That part is declared now, still no luck

Comment: trying changing "$name_array[] = array("name" => $name);" to array_push($name_array, $name);

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're getting a bunch of blank options?

```
<option value="0">- Select -</option>
```

Is the right syntax: the option's value (when selected) will be 0, and it'll display Select.

So when you append new items in the ajax callback you'll want to have the options show something:

```
<option value='name'>NAME</option>
```

Comment: That makes sense. I am still getting the blank options, so i'm guessing it has to do with the response now.

Comment: In php, is name_array ever initialized (name_array = [])? I'm with majorlogic, we need some more info about what response comes back as.

Comment: I found out the issue, I had the type = json, not dataType = json.

Answer (score 0):

In fact your are not looping through the array name,

This should work :

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'search.php',
                type: 'json',
                success:function(response){

                    var result = $.parseJSON(response);

                    var len = result.length;

                    $("#sel1").empty();
                    for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){

                        $("#sel1").append("<option value='"+ result[i]['name']  +"'></option>");

                    }
                }
            });
        });

</script>


            <select id="sel1" multiple size="6">
                <option value="0">- Select -</option>
            </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access response as an array, right?

You'll need to do something like

```
$("#sel1").append("<option value='"+response[i].name+"'>"+response[i].name+"</option>");
```

to get the items out of the response array. (modified from majorlogic's answer)